# Highlight *other* occurrences of symbol

Tags: highlighting

I've found that using the `highlight-symbol-mode` provided by [highlight-symbol](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el) works very nicely for highlighting all occurrences of the symbol at point, **automatically** (without my pressing anything). However, I would like to highlight all **other** occurrences of the symbol at point: that is, the actual symbol point is on should **not** be highlighted.

I can't find anything in `customize-group highlight-symbol` or in [highlight-symbol.el](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/blob/master/highlight-symbol.el) for this. Through Google, I haven't found any reference to other packages that support the functionality I want.

How can I get automatic highlighting of all **other** occurrences of the symbol at point?

Comment: FWIW, I'm curious as to why you want to do that. Is it because highlighting the occurrence at point is distracting, or is there some special use case?

Comment: @Drew: I like to turn the idle delays on these sorts of things down to zero, which means they have to be unobtrusive. It is, indeed, quite distracting to have the highlight constantly shift with each new word you type.

Comment: Agree this is annoying while typing, for evil-users, it can be disabled in insert mode: `(with-eval-after-load 'evil (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook (lambda () (highlight-symbol-mode 0)) nil t) (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook (lambda () (highlight-symbol-mode 1)) nil t))` - I find this avoids the annoyance of the current word at the cursor being highlighted.

Comment: I think there's hardly the need for an external package. Take a look at `isearch-forward-symbol`, `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`, `hightlight-symbol-at-point`, etc. These are all bound to the `M-s` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

See: [idle-highlight-mode](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-idle-highlight-mode/) which has an option `idle-highlight-exclude-point` to exclude highlighting the symbol at the point.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this package, thanks for pointing it out! It is perfect for prog modes.